# Read a text file using powershell only work on powershell screen command but not from script

Tags: powershell

I want to write a powershell command to read from a text file using Get-Content command.
But the Get-Content only works on windows powershell but not a script using it.

[image]

And this is the same script to use that command and executed by powershell itself.

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\thang.hoang\Desktop\New folder\New folder\New folder - Copy\ProjectName.txt"
read -p "Enter to continue"
```

[image]

It does not work at all.Is it something i miss to include to run the command?

Comment: Bash has no idea about powershell cmdlets. is there a reason to save it as `.sh` instead of .`ps1`?

Comment: Thank you because from the beginning i want to make a bash file that run from windows and mac at the same time with just a little bit of modifications.
Now i just realized that powershell and bash are different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the feeling there is something wrong with the scripts file format...
Like I can see that you call .\test2.sh which isn't a valid powershell script ending.
If you want to execute the script as a powershell script try the .ps1 ending.